# Pitest plugin is not detecting junit5 dependency

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit4, junit5, pitest

I'm upgrading an old application and it has the pitest plugin to improve the unit testing. Some newer tests are junit 5, so I added the junit5 plugin. However when I run the tests, it does not detect the plugin. What am I missing?

My POM plugin in :

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <targetClasses>
                    <param>nl.proj.proj*</param>
                </targetClasses>
                <targetTests>
                    <param>nl.proj.proj*</param>
                </targetTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I run the tests with the command:

> mvn test-compile org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage

Application details:
Spring boot 2.7
Junit 4 & 5 tests
Java 11

The message I get:

```
13:19:49 PIT >> WARNING : JUnit 5 is on the classpath but the pitest junit 5 plugin is not installed (https://github.com/pitest/pitest-junit5-plugin)
13:19:49 PIT >> INFO : Created 24 mutation test units in pre scan
13:19:49 PIT >> INFO : Sending 31 test classes to minion
13:19:49 PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
13:19:49 PIT >> SEVERE : Pitest could not run any tests. Please check that you have installed the pitest plugin for your testing library (eg JUnit 5, TestNG). If your project uses JUnit 4 the plugin is automatically included, but a recent version of JUnit 4 must be on the classpath.
```

Additional information from the exception:

```
[ERROR] Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
[ERROR] VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
[ERROR] Vendor : Eclipse Adoptium
[ERROR] Version : 11.0.18+10
[ERROR] Uptime : 10828
[ERROR] Input -> 
[ERROR]  1 : -Dclassworlds.conf=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec/bin/m2.conf
[ERROR]  2 : -Dmaven.home=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec
[ERROR]  3 : -Dlibrary.jansi.path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.1/libexec/lib/jansi-native
[ERROR]  4 : -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/riekele/IdeaProjects/rass-idin-idb
[ERROR] BootClassPathSupported : false
```

Comment: What happens if you use the latest version of the plugin (1.2.0)?

Comment: Did not fix the problem. Still same issue.